# Xcode lldb error - unsure where to start

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, exc-bad-access

I've been working on a small app, actually in final staging of polish and debug.

I made few small changes to `NSUserDefaults` storage, which were very minor changes.

However, every time I try to run the app on iPod I get a weird LLDB error, without any further info, like which file, library etc... I set up breakpoints in `application:didFinishLoadingWithOptions`, but the error is before that?? The app is stuck on splashscreen.

Dump if it is on any help...

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x2fd77d4c)
0x2fd77d4c:  svchs  #14122336
0x2fd77d50:  svchs  #14122908
0x2fd77d54:  svchs  #14122923
0x2fd77d58:  svchs  #14122954
0x2fd77d5c:  andeq  r0, r0, r0
0x2fd77d60:  rsbvc  r7, r1, #49283072
0x2fd77d64:  rsbvs  r6, pc, #3008
0x2fd77d68:  svchs  #6646889
```

Comment: Does it work OK on the simulator or in debug builds, but crashes when using release builds on the device only?

Comment: It works in simulator but not on device, regardless of run or debug.

Answer (score 0):

Does an empty project works with your iPOD? If the answer is yes, comment out all codes you wrote then uncomment it part by part to find which part caused this issue, vise versa.

It's always effective to slice suspect codes to pieces when you can't locate the issue.

Comment: There are multiple classes. The breakpoint very early in the appdelegate does not even trigger.

Comment: No, I mean you create an empty project then run it on iPod directly to see if it works or not.

Comment: i posted debug
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967129/ios-app-crashes-exc-bad-access-during-splashscreen