# iOS app crashes exc_bad_access during splashscreen

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

Before I even able to insert any breakpoints in the appdelegate.m... App does work in simulator but not on ipod touch. sometimes it does run, i'm unsure how to reproduce successful runs...

here's debug log:

```
dyld: loaded: /var/mobile/Applications/D7F06B5F-7D51-45C7-8344-B9CD9CD348D9/PagerPlus.app/PagerPlus
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
_dyld_register_func_for_add_image(0x3c314cc9)
PagerPlus(14958) malloc: recording malloc stacks to disk using standard recorder
_dyld_get_image_slide(0x6000)
dladdr(0x3c34b48d, 0x2fdf84ac)
PagerPlus(14958) malloc: stack logs being written into /private/var/mobile/Applications/D7F06B5F-7D51-45C7-8344-B9CD9CD348D9/tmp/stack-logs.14958.PagerPlus.index
PagerPlus(14958) malloc: Please issue: cp /private/var/mobile/Applications/D7F06B5F-7D51-45C7-8344-B9CD9CD348D9/tmp/stack-logs.14958.PagerPlus.f93OCU.link /tmp/
_dyld_register_func_for_remove_image(0x3c314d15)
_dyld_register_func_for_remove_image(0x3bedd961)
dyld_register_image_state_change_handler(40, 1, 0x3bed5189)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x3c417000)
dlopen(/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x3c2f2000)
dlopen(/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x3c3fd000)
dlopen(/usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x3bed4000)
dlopen(/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x34136000)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x33e4d000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x34a5e000)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x380a1000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x3b755000)
dlopen(/usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x3956d000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x3abef000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x385b4000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x36ffe000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x3686d000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x36d4a000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x3565d000)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x37337000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x375ef000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x38f0b000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x36d83000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x36c9c000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x348ca000)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x38542000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x34810000)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x39726000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x35515000)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x37563000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x34721000)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x37ff8000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x39544000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x34867000)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x35daa000)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x345de000)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x398e3000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x39d73000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x3a137000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x3aa67000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x3a117000)
dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x35ffd000)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit, 0x00000010)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x6000)
dyld_register_image_state_change_handler(45, 0, 0x3bed6ef9)
(lldb)
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the frameworks which are for phone supported devices (like Core Telephony...)

Comment: i do need telephony since the app uses phone when available. it used to work fine on both ipod and iphone 5 minutes ago and I don't think i made any significant changes, few minor additions (but only to the already loaded app, nothing in appdelegdate)

Answer (score 0):

Simulator simulates iphone or ipad devices. An ipod does not have phone support. Check to see if the Telephony frameworks (or anything not supported on ipod devices) are marked as "Optional" not "Required" in the link binary with libraries section of Build Phases. If you require something not supported it may not run on an ipod device. I would expect to see an error to that effect though I don't know what it would look like.

Comment: the telephony  framework is not in the list of linked libraries/frameworks at all.